# Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151 contains a valid JDK installation

Tags: java, android, gradle

Even though I manually configured JDK project structure [file/Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxQ2W.jpg) it still shows this error 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

`What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sample:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151 contains a valid JDK installation.`

I'm confused why it is still looking for C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151 instead of JDK

Comment: What is the current value of the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable? And is the JRE higher in your `PATH`? Why even install a JRE (the JDK includes one)?

Comment: I have jdk1.7.0_79, jdk1.8.0_144, jre1.8.0_151 inside c:/windows/program Files/ java

Comment: That does not answer any one of my three distinct questions. Also, `c:/windows/program Files/`? Are you sure?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxQ2W.jpg, and for the second one  the JRE is same as mentioned in the terminal  C:\Program Files\Java is my directory where JDK remains, by default in Android studio it was this directory configured in my studio  C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

Comment: `echo %PATH%` and `echo %JAVA_HOME%`.

Comment: For JAVA_HOME its C:\Users\viswesvar>echo %JAVA_HOME%
%JAVA_HOME%   For  echo %JAVA_HOME% C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files

Comment: I fixed it by adding JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

Comment: For MacOS users, check out my answer on another thread: [Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Could not find tools.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65560333/988521)

Comment: My problem was that I had to use JDK instead of JRE.

Answer (score 124):

At last, here I found the solution.

I added jdk path `org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144` to `gradle.properties` file and did a rebuild. It works now.

Comment: This works like a charm. gradle.properties file is located in project root directory. If not create a new file gradle.properties
For Windows this worked for me  org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_171

Comment: how about on osx tho? any idea how to get that path?

Comment: I am getting this error Value 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)

Comment: Just Go to your Program File JDK install path like me have 
org.gradle.java.home= ""
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

and add front slash like above answer

Answer (score 108):

```
ERROR: Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121 contains a valid JDK installation
```

Copy **tools.jar** from `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\lib` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8\lib`.

It's resolved the problem now.

Comment: I just updated my Android Studio from version 3.2 to version 3.3 and then faced this problem. After hours of googling your solution finally helped me. Thanks!

Comment: After trying so many solutions (changing editors, installing new plugins ...), this one solved my problem, thanks.

Comment: This solution works fine for me. Stunned by copy/paste of tools.jar file manually. Anyway great solution.

Comment: This solution worked for me too, thank you  But this is really weird This really needs to be done automatically 

Comment: Damn JDK. Was not able to add it to the system variables as well. But just copying the tools.jar worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 39):

Just had this happen to me.

Apparently Java's automatic updater installed and configured a new version of the JRE for me, while leaving the old JDK intact. So even though I did have a JDK, it didn't match the currently "active" JRE, which was causing the error.

**[Download *a matching version* of the JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) to the JRE you currently have installed,** (In OP's case 151) That should do the trick.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem and fixed it like this:

1. Install the JDK from the Oracle website with the same version number
   as the JRE if you didn't already.
2. Furthermore add JAVA_HOME to the environment variables of Windows.
3. Restart your terminal or development environment to load the new JAVA_HOME value.

[image: JAVE_HOME in System Environment Variables]

Answer (score 4):

This happens when JDK and JRE have different versions installed on your system. Update the JDK with the matching version of JRE. Also verify that System variable path has bin value from same JDK version.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your gradle build is not finding the JAVA_HOME path or JDK folder. So, you could declare the path in gradle.properties like ***org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\[or yours jdk folder name]***.

Use [this guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) for using gradle.properties.

Or (and I prefer this solution) ***include JAVA_HOME path in systmem variables*** and restart CMD.

[image]

Comment: Tank you. for those of us that want a solution to work on multiple operating systems with different file paths this is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you can not find **Tools.jar** in **JAVA_HOME**, You can use this method. But you have to have **Android Studio** in your PC.

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio\\jre
```

Place this in `your project > android > gradle.properties`

Answer (score 2):

What I did was I uninstalled Java from my PC, and then downloaded and installed JDK again from Oracle. After this it worked perfectly. I think the problem was because the JRE and JDK update version were different from each other.

Answer (score 2):

My error was solved by uninstalling all java updates and java from control panel and reinstalling JDK

Answer (score 2):

My issue was two-fold:

1. I had the JRE installed, but *not* the JDK.
2. I did not have a JAVA_HOME environment variable set.

Note: I am using Fedora Linux.

To resolve the first issue, I followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-centos-and-fedora)

To resolve the second, I merely added the following line to my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java/
```

I had to restart my IDE and terminals to ensure the change to the `~/.bashrc` took affect.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

1. Go to your android folder > Gradle.properties > add your jdk path.
2. Clean and rebuild then it is done.
   // For Example Purpose Only

   org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home

**Solution 2**
At last, here I found the solution.

1. Add jdk path

   ```
   to gradle.properties file and did a rebuild.
   ```
2. This will also solve your error.

Here is all Solution **[could not find tools.jar](https://fluttercorner.com/how-to-solve-flutter-could-not-find-tools-jar/)**

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure both JDK and jre are on same version for example if you have JRE version **1.8.0_201** then JDK version should be  **1.8.0_201** version.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was download the JDK from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html), start a windows command prompt (windows+r CMD) and set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14 with:

```
set JAVA_HOME="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14"
```

Then run what I wanted to run. It failed afterwards, but on a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because the JAVA_HOME path could not find it.

- Close all terminals and open a new one
- Find a directory like this on your **Mac**:
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
- What may change is the version, but once you have it, it runs in that
  path:
  export JAVA_HOME = / Library / Java / JavaVirtualMachines /
  jdk1.8.0_91.jdk / Contents / Home

IN MY CASE I RUN THIS COMMAND AT THE ROOT OF THE REACT NATIVE PROJECT:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

AND IT WORKED.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when I installed the new android studio version and this solution works for me, so if you don't have JDK installed in the java folder or isn't the same version as JRE then you should install it (should JRE and JDK be in the same version, for example, both of them be in this version 1.8.0).

install it from this link => [download JDK from Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html)

then copy tools.jar from (JDK folder) ==> jdk1.8.0../lib  and paste it in (JRE folder) ==> jre1.8.0../lib

Answer (score 1):

To Solve ERROR: Could not find tools.jar. Please check that **C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151** contains a valid JDK installation Error You Just need to add the java home JDK path in gradle.properties Just like this:
`org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144` Then try to rebuild project. Now your error must be solved.

The second solution is You just need to add tools.jar file to **C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8\lib** this Path. First of all Copy tools.jar file from **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\lib** and then Paste into **C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8\lib** Here. Now your error must be solved

Answer (score 0):

for tools.jar is in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\lib. I changed installed jre in eclipse. Windows->Preferences->Java->installed JREs and make default jre to point to where your jdk is.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if your path is too long as well. I solved this by moving my java install to

C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_211

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was updating Android Studio and updating JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME environment variables. I believe it was caused due to the fact that I updated Java Version (through updater) but did not update jdk.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse

Right click Project --> Java Build Path --> Libraries

1. Remove the JRE
2. Click on Add Library --> JRE System Library -->Next -->Alternate JRE --> installed JRE --> Add JDK and select and Apply

Comment: Thanks a lot, All i had to do was update the version of jre to 1.8 through this method and it worked

Answer (score 0):

you have to added jdk path org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102 to gradle.properties
make sure you write your jdk version which installed in you system.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had installed only the JRE so you could check to make sure you actually have a valid jdk. if not i advise you to uninstall whatever java is installed and [download a correct jdk from here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) (the jdk comes with a jre so no need to download anything else) after set the environment variable and your done

Answer (score 0):

**Goto android folder** -> **gradle.properties** ->
add your java sdk path

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Users/userName/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_302/Contents/Home/jre
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add system environment variable JAVA_HOME and restart workspace. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you guys needs to check on your tool versions.
below version may solve most of the problems.

1. jdk - v11
2. node - v16.13.1
3. Gradle - v6.1.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After I've read the threads above, there are three approaches I've tried that work for me:

- open system variable environment, add a new system variable named `JAVA_HOME` and set its value to your JDK path containing the 'tools.jar' file e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311`.
- create a `gradle.properties` file in your project and add the following line `org.gradle.java.home=<your JDK path e.g. C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_311>`
- copy the "tools.jar" file from your JDK folder and paste it in the JRE folder that caused the error. You could find your jar file in lib folder of your jdk path e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\lib`

Answer (score -1):

I tried several of the above ways, but none worked for me, try the following; download the following java version [Link download in Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html), after downloading and installing it, add this to the gradle.properties file
`org.gradle.java.home = C: \\ Program Files \\ Java \\ jdk1.8.0_301` and that's it, restart the vs code and simulate again, and it worked!