# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Could not find tools.jar

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get this error while executing

```
react-native run-android
```

I have tried copying tools.jar file to JRE installation location, reinstalled JDK and JRE, checked environment variables for path. Nothing worked.

It returned with the below exception

```
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_211 contains a valid JDK installation

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291056/could-not-find-tools-jar-please-check-that-c-program-files-java-jre1-8-0-151-c) might be helpful for you

Comment: yeah, that helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to **gradle.properties**:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_91
```

Don’t forget to use double back slashes. For example:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144\
```

Answer (score 14):

For MacOS, here are the steps:

1. Get Current java version ( recommended 1.8 ):

> ```
> $ java -version  
> java version "1.8.0_271"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)
> ```

2. CD to your Java home path

> ```
> $ cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
> $ ls
> total 0
> drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B 24 Out 09:24 adoptopenjdk-15-openj9.jre
> drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B 30 Dez 20:18 jdk1.8.0_271.jdk
> ```

3. CD to the current java home shown at step 1 (" java 1.8.0_271" ):

> ```
> $ cd jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home
> ```

Note: if you can't find `1.8.0_271.jdk` after listing the files in the folder, you might find another jdk file like this `adoptopenjdk-8.jdk` use it.

4. Copy the current path to clipboard:

> ```
> $ pwd | pbcopy
> ```

5. Finally, open the **gradle.properties** file (here I'm using VSCode) and set the **org.gradle.java.home** variable:

```html
org.gradle.java.home=<path_to_current_java_home>
```

Her is an working example:

[image]

Comment: saved my life :D

Comment: THANK YOU. This.

Answer (score 1):

This is because valid jdk path could not be detected. Go to your project, open android folder > gradle.properties file > add below line:

`org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`

and you are good to go ;)

Answer (score 0):

For me in MacOS the path to put in gradle.properties was:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```