# Trying to run react-native project on emulator

Tags: react-native, emulation, asyncstorage, tools.jar

I was working with someone on a project and he give me the access for the project I clone it perfectly and I easy install the node module but when i try to run the project in emulator I face this issue when is not resolving at all.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56389284/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-could-not-find-too) answer your question?

Comment: No, but later i find a solution , i was having 2 jdk kits  first, jre 1.8... and second jdk 1.8.. so i just copy tool.jar from jdk1.8 >lib and paste it in jre 1.8 >lib where already tool.jar was (i delete that one )