# React native build fail react-native-fbsdk

Tags: gradle, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Trying to build react-native android app but following error

> info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can
>   disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag. Jetifier found 1108 file(s) to
>   forward-jetify. Using 12 workers... info JS server already running.
>   info Installing the app...
>
> > Task :react-native-fbsdk:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 6.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>   26 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 24 up-to-date
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231 contains a valid JDK installation.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4s
>
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
>   development environment set up:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment.
>   Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Error: Command failed:
>   gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231 contains a valid JDK installation.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4s
>
> ```
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:603:11)
> at execFileSync (child_process.js:621:13)
> at runOnAllDevices (G:\work\upveda\app\2019\rn_subhakamana\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
> at buildAndRun (G:\work\upveda\app\2019\rn_subhakamana\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
> at then.result (G:\work\upveda\app\2019\rn_subhakamana\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! Subhakamana@0.0.1
> ```
>
> android: `react-native run-android` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the Subhakamana@0.0.1 android script. npm ERR! This
>   is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\sheye\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-19T11_54_40_308Z-debug.log

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291056/could-not-find-tools-jar-please-check-that-c-program-files-java-jre1-8-0-151-c

Comment: first try ```npm i jetifier``` and then ```npx jetify```

Comment: @GauravRoy it works. Some explanation would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the problem was  you have to perform an AndroidX migration on your linked source every time you update react native modules that ship native Java code. That is what this tool(i.e jetifier and jetify command) does - it can rewrite the source in node_modules every time you call it.

the commands are first try `npm i jetifier` and then `npx jetify` to solve your problem.

Hope it helps, feel free for doubts