# Flutter could not find tools.jar

Tags: macos, flutter

Hi today I've upgrade my MacBook to macOS Big Sur version 11.0.1. Now there is a problem coming out.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':apple_sign_in:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**THREAD CLOSED**

I'm a Mac user. I've found the solution by using this method.

1. Go to your android folder > Gradle.properties > add your jdk path.

```
// Example 
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
```

2. Clean and rebuild then it's done.

Comment: I would suggest using Android Studio provided jre as follows;
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: @Jona, What would be the benefit of this other than consistent behaviour between the IDE and OS (e.g. Terminal)? Just curious, Thanks!

Comment: @ddsultan Android Studio provides its own JRE as you can see from the path I suggested. It's likely heavily tested by Google on every new Android Studio release. So that would be the primary reason for my suggestion. Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm curios, since gradle.properties normally isn't gitignored; wouldn't this change affect the entire team? Would it be better or possible to add this to local.properties instead?

Comment: @Jona in my case the path was different so following worked for me: 
`org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/`

Answer (score 29):

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/64864365/2405040.

You should not alter `gradle.properties` manually. Try setting your `JAVA_HOME` in `~/.bash_profile` to something like-

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
```

then relaunch a terminal session or run

```sh
source ~/.bash_profile
```

If you are using Zsh/Oh-My-Zsh, add the above with file `~/.zshrc` and then reload the same or relaunch the terminal-

```sh
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Combining this with another comment I am using `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home` to rely on the Android Studio bundled version.

Answer (score 4):

Solution of u problem -> [Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151 contains a valid JDK installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291056/could-not-find-tools-jar-please-check-that-c-program-files-java-jre1-8-0-151-c)

> At last, here I found the solution.
>
> I added jdk path

```
org.gradle.java.home=YOU_PATH_TO_JDK
```

to gradle.properties file and did a rebuild.

> It works now.

Comment: I added this "org.gradle.java.home=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_251" and I got an error. 
* What went wrong:
Value '\usr\local\java\jdk1.8.0_251' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid).

Comment: What`s editor u use (Idea\Android studio\VS)?
Try fix u JAVA_HOME variable

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment, but here's a macOS one-liner based on the other answers if you use ZSH (Catalina+ default). No need to install Java from Oracle.

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: This helped me after updating android studio. Thanks

Comment: Check Android Studio directory to check correct path. My path was and has worked for me: echo 'export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home"' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 4):

This issue is Mac specific and reading online it appears that often after updating the OS this problem will happen.

I resolved this by removing the following internet plugin:

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```

Strange that this is what did it, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use FVM and use Flutter 2.2.3

For Intel Mac users

go to Android -> gradle.properties

and add following at end of the file

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/
```

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwxMU.png)

Answer (score -1):

I was facing this issue and the simple solution that worked for me was:

1. Did a clean installation of jdk8 in mac
   and add the path to environmental variables (`JAVA_HOME`).

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Ho$
   ```
2. Restarted the computer.