# Ionic + Cordova Android build error - could not find tools.jar

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, macos-big-sur

today I've upgrade my MacBook to macOS Big Sur version 11.0.1. Now there is a problem coming out when I tried to build the project for Android.

```
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.
```

Comment: check your JDK and path. I recommend you to reinstall Java JDK.

Comment: I run in terminal `/usr/libexec/java_home` and result is `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` . I assumed java path and JDK is working fine.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I also faced the same issue today while the same setup (building the Android app) was working for me before upgrading to Big Sur.

I saw various solutions like-

1. [Flutter could not find tools.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64820672/flutter-could-not-find-tools-jar)
2. [Not able to run Eclipse on macOS Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62647625/not-able-to-run-eclipse-on-macos-big-sur)

But I was not sure if those were recommended solution. I tried for few hours and finally got it working with the correct fix (looks to me).

Basically, for me, the `JAVA_HOME` variable was not set (or Big Sur removed it somehow).

So I simply added it in my `~/.zshrc` (or `~/.bashrc`)-

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You can simply check and replace the version number in the above line.

Comment: After the Big Sur update, the JAVA_HOME variable was removed from my ```~ /.bashrc ``` thanks

Comment: How to open .bashrc or .zshrc file ?

Comment: for a long time, finally found it too. thanks guys this works perfectly in big sur

Comment: @zulkarnainshah go to your root directory & press `cmd + shirt + . (dot)` you can see .bashrc & .zshrc files

Answer (score 50):

Try running

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

And see if this shows in the list

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

This was the case for me and I had to remove the entries to the Internet Plug-Ins folder. Check [here](https://www.talkapex.com/2020/11/sqldeveloper-in-macos-big-sur/) for more details that helped me.

Comment: Error occoured after Big Sur update, tried out all the other solution, only this one solved it. Thanks!

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: This fixed it for me as well.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me big time!

Comment: Worked for me too, IONIC stack

Comment: In case anyone is hesistant to completely delete the folder, simply renaming it solved the issue for me as well

Comment: Fixed, Thanks a lot 

Comment: Great fix. Thanks man. Saved lots of time

Comment: I have been stuck on this for 2 days thanks man!! cheers!

Answer (score 26):

If this is not still resolved for the Cordova android build -- just do it manually.
My case:
java_home is set properly and also reloaded ~/.zshrc (or ~/.bashrc) files. And I am getting JAVA_HOME value by echoing on terminal.

So I manually copied file **tool.jar** from `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/lib` to
`/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib`
And It worked.

For ease use this cmd

`sudo cp /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib`

Just check your JAVA JDK version.

Comment: Typo or not? I had 1.8.0.121.jdk NOT _211.  In addition I also followed this: https://explainjava.com/set-java-home-mac-os/

Answer (score 15):

The issue happens because of the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is not correctly set.

Step 1 - Confirm that you have issue with `JAVA_HOME` by printing its value in the terminal. You will most likely get an empty string.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Step 2 - Find the correct path on your machine

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

Copy that path associated with "Java SE 8" which usually looks like `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home`

Step 3 - Edit `.zshenv` using `nano`

```
nano ~/.zshenv
```

Step 4 - Add the path from step 2 to the file as follows

```
export JAVA_HOME=YOUR_JAVA_PATH
```

example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Step 5 - Source the updated `.zshenv` file to activate the environment variable

```
source ~/.zshenv
```

Step 6 - Print to confirm the path

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 2):

After updating Mac Os to Big Sur I faced the same problem,
Solution :

- Download the latest JDK 8 from : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html
- and Installed it

Comment: me 2. i have downloaded the latest version. for example jdk-8u291. then i ran this cmd and problem fixed.

sudo cp /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib

Comment: That really worked for me cool... thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue occurs because `JAVA_HOME` path updated with
`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`
which have many issues

While runing `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` on terminal found:

```
1.8.151.12 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
1.8.0_151 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
```

so I changed it to use old working one

Answer (score 0):

I also solved the same problem by **downloading the latest version of jdk 8** and installing it.
I also set my .bash_profile (it can be the one of your preference), adding the JAVA path as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-latest-version/Contents/Home"
```