# Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Could not find tools.jar

Tags: android, flutter, macos

I'd tried to used flutter to development, but when I used android emulator I got this error.

`Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Could not find tools.jar`

I tried add

`android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true`

or

`org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

in gradle.properties, but it was same issues.

And when I command flutter doctor, I got this information.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale en-AU)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ Android Studio not found at /path/to/android/studio/Contents
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    ! Error: S  iPhone is busy: Fetching debug symbols for S  iPhone. Xcode will
      continue when S  iPhone is finished. (code -10)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

How can fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64820672/flutter-could-not-find-tools-jar

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:/users//.gradle/cache  delete everything then run again. I hope this helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31834494)