# Missing JDK from my react native project/application. Could Not find Tools.jar or JDK

Tags: java, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I am receiving the error below upon executing cd andorid ./gradle assemble. It seems my project is missing a path to JDK how can I add/correct this?

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
17 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 15 up-to-date
```

```
mattlaszcz@Matts-MBP android % /usr/libexec/java_home -V | grep jdk
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.8.291.10 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0\_151 contains a valid JDK installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291056/could-not-find-tools-jar-please-check-that-c-program-files-java-jre1-8-0-151-c)

Comment: yes somewhat..im trying to have my JAVA_HOME path match the path of the installation of JAVA on my Mac and I am just not sure how to accomplish this

Comment: usually setting `JAVA_HOME=YOUR_JDK_PATH` and adding `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to your `PATH` variable helps.

Comment: yes! how can I find my JDK path and add $JAVA_HOME/bin to my path variable..I keep seeing these responses but I am not sure how to accomplish them is my issue.